# Shortcut for "move to left editor" and "move to right editor" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

If I've got my Eclipse windows split vertically, is there any keyboard shortcut to move to the logical left/right editor?

For example, in the image blow, the right editor is selected, and I want to move to the left window:

[image: split windows]

For those of you who know Vim, I am trying to recreate `c-w h` and `c-w l`.

Comment: Visual Studio has an action for this too that can be assigned to a key. I'm with you; I wish I could do it in Eclipse...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The answer from Csaba_H is right : there is no keyboard shortcut to switch from one editor area to the next. The most you can do through keyboard shortcuts is to switch to "another editor", whatever its area is (left, right, top, bottom... whatever you tiled the area into :p) through the usual shortcuts :

- next editor : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
- previous editor : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>
- quick switch editor : <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>

I'll only mention that you can also take a look yourself to all available shortcuts in your Eclipse if you go to Window > preferences and go into the section General > Keys (a shortcut to get there is to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> twice).

Answer (score 17):

Personally I did not find such shortcut or option. However, there are some possibilities for switching editors from the keyboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> as general ones, or my favourite "all-in-one" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> :) ).

Also, if you work mostly two files 'for a long time' (one in left side and one on right side), you can also use the History operations (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>) for switching editors.

Eclipse allows for multiple editors to be open at any time, and those editors may be arranged as tabs (default behaviour) or split vertically or horizontally.  The information above about available shortcut options is correct and provides the correct functionality in the case of two (only) open editors.  Where there are greater than two open editors the shortcuts allow navigation to the 'next' or 'previous' editor.  There is no concept of the logical left/right or top/bottom editor.

Answer (score 5):

Just found it!

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>.

Comment: Possibly my configuration is different then yours, but for me that moves between tabs and not between windows.

Comment: This just cycles through tabs within the same editor, not move tabs to a different editor.

Answer (score 4):

It's just Ctrl + Tab and Ctrl + Shift + Tab on my windows! try it.

Comment: Thanks, I don't see why this is not accepted solution. It is exactly what OP asks.

Comment: It is not an accepted solution because it does not answer the question. Ctrl + Tab do not move to the editor in the right of the current, but to the previously edited

Answer (score 1):

In all my eclipse usage I've never noticed such a shortcut and I would not expect one to exist. I skimmed though the link provided by Anthony and checked my own copy of eclipse, but none of it looked like what you're looking for.

You can also look through them yourself by going to: Window > Preferences > General > Keys

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't any shortcut in there :(

Comment: @DavidWolever There's `Next Editor` and `Previous Editor`. I set mine to CTRL+TAB and CTRL+SHIFT+TAB

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is something in vanilla Eclipse, but you might want to check out "Emacs+" in the Eclipse Marketplace.

From http://www.mulgasoft.com/ :

"Other Window (Ctrl-X O): Navigate to the previous editor window"

It's not perfect, but it will achieve something close to what you want.

You can also split the window with shortcuts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Access <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> has been very useful in Eclipse.

Otherwise, I know of two external programs that navigate by dividing the screen into smaller chunks, using only your keyboard.

If you're on **Windows**, you can use [Mouser](http://lifehacker.com/212816/hack-attack-operate-your-mouse-with-your-keyboard), which is coded in Autohotkey and based on keynav. If you find the source, remapping the keys is fairly straightforward.

If you're on **Linux**, [keynav](https://github.com/jordansissel/keynav) is your friend.

```
sudo apt-get install keynav
```

You'll have to change the configuration file to use arrow keys. (The default uses vim-like navigation.)

For focusing panels in Eclipse, I average between two-to-three keystrokes.