# How to make eclipse allow autohotkey shortcuts to work?

Tags: eclipse, autohotkey

Since [eclipse doesn't have functionality to easily switch which split-screen editor you're using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627189/shortcut-for-move-to-left-editor-and-move-to-right-editor-in-eclipse) I tried writing an Autohotkey script to just click on the upper corner of the halves.

The AHK script works great... in any application except Eclipse. It seems that eclipse binds the shortcut and won't let go of it. I have removed all instances of <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> from the general --> keys in eclipse preferences.

Using:

- Eclipse Helios
- Newest version of AHK
- Win 7 (in a VM)

How can I make eclipse relinquish control of this shortcut?

The test script in question (I'm testing with just up, will add down once this works):

```
^Up::
Click 901, 81
```

Comment: Java based GUI tends to be stubborn...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution:

I was running eclipse as administrator. Compiling the script to a standalone executable and running that as an administrator solved the issue.

Comment: You should also be able to right-click the .ahk file and "Run As Administrator" without compiling.

Comment: @echristopherson I don't see it on by default, but in searching for the answer I found that you can enable that with a registry edit.. I just didn't care enough to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Loop
{
        if (GetKeyState("CTRL"))
        {
                if (GetKeyState("UP"))
                {
                        Click 901, 81
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: No luck. I wasn't sure whether or not to keep the `^Up::` at the beginning, so I tried it both ways